# Why is my CleanBot stuck at the front door?

Tags: the-sims-2

So, in Sims 2 I had my sim make a cleanbot and had it running just fine. However, in the most recent winter season, the cleanbot is stuck at my front door and won't budge, so I can't even replace the door... What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you had already saw [this forum](http://modthesims.info/t/584249), and are aware of it, but it seems that when cleanbots go broken, they can not go through doors any more. In that case, get your sim to fix it and should be working fine again. If it is not broken, and still does this, it could be the door itself is to blame. According to the same site, the bots are not that very good with simple, one tiles doors, double doors are recommended.

Comment: Thanks for this. I decided to just use the old "boolProp testingcheatsenabled true" and force an error on both the cleanbot and the dock so I could delete them.  Also, yes, I did see that forum post. It wasn't broken and needed to be repaired or anything, it was just sitting there. So weird!